# Não consigo centralizar usando o grid

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, grid

justify-content não funciona no meu grid, coloco justify-content no .content e nada acontece.

CSS:

```css
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
                "p pn e"
                "pr es s";                  
    width: 45vw;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color:var(--Cinza);
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.perfil {
    grid-area: p;
}

.perfil-nome {
    grid-area: pn;
}

.editar {
    grid-area: e;
}

.projetos {
    grid-area: pr;
}

.estrelas {
    grid-area: es;
}

.seguidores {
    grid-area: s;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <article class="profile">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="perfil">
                    <div class="foto-perfil"></div>
                </div> 
                <div class="perfil-nome">
                    <p class="nome">Bruno Max</p>
                    <p class="arroba">@bruno-oli</p>
                </div>
                <div class="editar">
                    <img src="images/edit-solid.svg" alt="Editar">
                    <span>Editar</span>
                </div>
                <div class="projetos">
                    <p class="p-titulo">Projetos</p>
                    <p class="p-numero">27</p>
                </div>
                <div class="estrelas">
                    <p class="p-titulo">Estrelas</p>
                    <p class="p-numero">302</p>
                </div>
                <div class="seguidores">
                    <p class="p-titulo">Seguidores</p>
                    <p class="p-numero">83</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </main>
```

Comment: coloque `margin: 0 auto;` na class "content"

Answer (score -2):

Vamos partir do pressuposto que voê quer centralizar o container na pagina, se for isso o pai do .profile precisa ter alguns seletores, ja que o objetivo é centralizar seu filho que é o proprio .container

.profile {
display: grid;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

OBS: Uma dica, coloque sempre background coloridos para ver melhor o comportamento.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).